# Angular2 [src] causing 404 error when loading image dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, http-status-code-404

i´ll try to load an image after the page is loaded into a modal form that opens on click.

My image Tag looks like this:

```
<img src="/src/files/bstand{{detailEntry.bearbeitungsstand}}.png">
```

The image source is correct. But when i load the page my variable detailentry is empty because i am fill it on click of a button. 
so the console shows me a 404 error with url:
"/src/files/bstand.png"
which does not exist
Wehen ic Click the button the image is loaded properly.

I remember that i used `ng_src` in angular 1 and the equivalent shout be `[src]` i thought but it does not work.

Thank you for any answer!

Comment: did u try [src]="'/src/files/bstand' + detailEntry.bearbeitungsstand + '.png'" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the detailEntry with ngIf

```
<img *ngIf="detailEntry.bearbeitungsstand" src="/src/files/bstand{{detailEntry.bearbeitungsstand}}.png">
```

Comment: Thanks that was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could use *ngIf to keep the image tag from being rendered without a valid src.

```
<img *ngIf="detailEntry.bearbeitungsstand" src="/src/files/bstand{{detailEntry.bearbeitungsstand}}.png">
```

Comment: Thanks that was the answer!